# Uploading files to github website using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, github, urllib

I'm making a game with pygame (Python 3), and one of the features I want to add is the option to upload one's score (as a file) to my github website (a github repository at aes-encoding.github.io) upon completion. Is there a simple way to do so? Let's say, through urllib?

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "github website".

Comment: There might be something I'm missing, but pretty sure that GitHub Pages (https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/) doesn't support any sort of easy dynamic coding.